# Deno, why i cannot get custom header

Tags: deno

[image]

In this picture,
I have send Aaaa and  MOck-Query-Path,
But in m Deno, i cannot get them, why.

```
Deno.serve(async (req) => {
    console.log(1111,req.headers);
```

Comment: I have cross domain

Comment: have done, prefilght resoponse header can resove it,thanks!

Comment: can you show the output of `req.headers` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Deno.serve` request object has access to all headers sent in the request, including custom headers. Use the `req.headers.get("header-name")` function to get the value for a specific header (not case-sensitive).

If you want an object with all of the headers, `Object.fromEntries(req.headers.entries())` - just note the resulting object's keys will be all normalized to lower case values.

Tested with Deno version 1.38.1

```
Deno.serve(async (req) => {
  console.log(req.headers.get("Mock-Query-Path"));
  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(req.headers.entries())),
  );
});
```

Test using curl

```bash
curl localhost:8000 \
  -H "Aaaa: 20231013-direct-mail" \
  -H "Mock-Query-Path: /customer/getCustomerDetails"
```

Console Output:

```bash
/customer/getCustomerDetails
```

Response

```json
{
  "aaaa": "20231013-direct-mail",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "host": "localhost:8000",
  "mock-query-path": "/customer/getCustomerDetails",
  "user-agent": "curl/7.81.0"
}
```